# WinJS and Apache cordova

Tags: cordova, winjs

At present we have technologies such as MS remoteapps and Citrix xenapp, both of which require clients to be running on the local PC.

Am I right in my thinking that I could use WinJS and Apache Cordova to create a wrap around windows applications like Excel & Chrome and stream them directly to a browser using JS and HTML5 without the need for a plugin?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to implement; just stream desktop or use the application that are on desktop. Streaming desktop is simply just taking picture of desktop and streaming it as video to browser. For utilization of the available applications you need different solution. Utilize COM Automation (functions in C++) for Excel or Chrome and call it by JavaScript for instance. [This means creating plugin.](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_plugin.md.html)

Though if you mean by plugin that you don't need to install anything into Excel/Chrome or on desktop, then no, you can not. There should be one component that sends the data/stream and another component that receives it.

I hope this helps you forward.